# unable to insert data into sqlite database in obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

hii every one

i am using following method to insert data into data base , but it will save the first entered value only all the time 
the following method is in the insertUpdateDelete class

```
- (void) InsertRecord {


    if(addStmt == nil) {

        NSString *nsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tbl_Users(FirstName,MiddleName) Values('%@','%@')",strFirstName,strMiddleName];
        const char *sql = [nsql UTF8String];



        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        }
    }



    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
        intID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}
```

through following code i am calling this method, tfText[0] & tfText[1] are text field variable , problem is,, on every click of save after entering some data in text field, it will save only the first entered value into the data base

```
 - (void) save_Clicked
    {


        iICS_testAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iICS_testAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        //Create a Items Object.
        insertUpdateDelete *objInsertUpdateDelete = [[insertUpdateDelete alloc] init];

        objInsertUpdateDelete.strFirstName = tfText[0].text;
        objInsertUpdateDelete.strMiddleName = tfText[1].text;

        [appDelegate InsertRecord:objInsertUpdateDelete];

    }
```

can any one help me,,,,thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char *addRecord = "insert into Test(taskname, desc) values(?, ?)";
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, addRecord, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"Error while Inserting Record :- '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return -1;
}

sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [Ttitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [Tdesc UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
{
    NSLog(@"Error1 while Inserting Record :- '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return -1;
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Record Inserted Successfully.");
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot ,it worked fine,,,my code also correct know y its not updating data?

Comment: Just Check the value for both the variable and debug your code...You will defenately get the solution.